# OpenSSL: Add new OIDs in a Certificate request

Tags: openssl, x509

I want to insert a new oid in a csr file with openssl through the configuration file openssl.cnf. This is a summary of my config file

```
# The default section
HOME                = .
openssl_conf        = openssl_init

[ openssl_init ]
oid_section         = oids[enter image description here][1]

[ oids ]
macAddress          = MAC Address, 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22

[ req ]
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = "IT"
emailAddress        = "dev2@test.com"
macAddress          = "12:34:56:78:9A:BC"
```

From terminal, I run this command:

```
openssl req -new -outform PEM -config ./iot-dev.conf -out ./iot-dev2.csr -keyout ./dev2-private.pem
```

But when I get the .csr file, the field happens in this format

[Output iot-dev2.csr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Em1v.png)

How can I show the correct name and the value of the OID ?

Thank you guys!